# emotional ontology

Tags: ontology, emotion

I want to make  application who detect emotions from a text. To do this i need a ontology. my question for you is, if you know a existent ontology who can help me.

Comment: +1 because... because... There is feeling in this question! Somewhere in my brain I think you are kidding, but somewhere else I think you are deadly serious... I don't know what is scarier! :-)

Comment: i do not get your irony. this question is serious. i do not want to make something what exists already. to create an ontology takes some time and i do not have enough time to create something what exists already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a markuplanguage draft from w3c for emotionML that could help 
http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-emotionml-20091029/

and there was a similar question on sematic overflow
http://www.semanticoverflow.com/questions/1383/ontologies-for-human-emotions-or-relating-persons-to-things

Comment: well some aplication or api which can help me to use a existing ontology you know?

Answer (score 1):

Try lymbix api. they have a decent ontology, though interpreting it might still be some work. http://www.lymbix.com/supportcenter/docs. Ofcourse they have very basic free version, and a paid version. I doubt they will be willing to give you a paid version if your application is anywhere close to rating emails.

Comment: That's cool.  It looks like they even classify for you:
     
    "article_sentiment": {"sentiment":"Positive",
                          "score":7.8}

Answer (score 1):

You can use [YAGO](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/yago-naga/yago/) which has information from Wikipedia and WordNet.

WordNet probably has everything you need, for example, here is everything narrower than the term [emotion](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&r=1&s=emotion&i=1&h=1000#c).  You can query WordNet using [JAWS](http://lyle.smu.edu/~tspell/jaws/) for Java.